# How to return an array of structs from a struct of arrays in Standard SQL?

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, array-agg

I have a non-repeated record column on my table that I want to access.
On this record, there are several repeated values.

So it is a `RECORD`, like so:

```
STRUCT<item ARRAY<STRING> unit_cost ARRAY<INT64> quantity ARRAY<INT64>> as costs
```

Eg. the data might represent:

```
item ['cheese', 'ham', 'salad']
unit_cost [2, 5, 8]
quantity [1, 2, 1]
```

So I want to return this as a nicer data structure, an array of structs:

```
[
  {'item': 'cheese', 'unit_cost': 2, 'quantity': 1}, 
  {'item': 'ham', 'unit_cost': 5, 'quantity': 2}
  {'item': 'salad', 'unit_cost': 8, 'quantity': 1}
]
```

I tried:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(costs)
```

but it results in

```
            [
              {
                "item": ['cheese', 'ham', 'salad'],
                "unit_cost": [2, 5, 8],
                "quantity": [1, 2, 1]
              }
            ]
```

which is not what I had expected it to return.

Is it possible to go from a `STRUCT` of multiple `ARRAY` to an `ARRAY` of multiple `STRUCT` using some clever use of Standard SQL here?

Answer (score 6):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT item, unit_cost, quantity
    FROM UNNEST(costs.item) item WITH OFFSET
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(costs.unit_cost) unit_cost WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(costs.quantity) quantity WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
  ) AS costs
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is (in JSON View)

```
[
  {
    "costs": [
      {
        "item": "cheese",
        "unit_cost": "2",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "item": "ham",
        "unit_cost": "5",
        "quantity": "2"
      },
      {
        "item": "salad",
        "unit_cost": "8",
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```sql
with data as (
select STRUCT<item ARRAY<STRING>, unit_cost ARRAY<INT64>, quantity ARRAY<INT64>>
  (['cheese', 'ham', 'salad'], [2, 5, 8], [1, 2, 1]) entry
union all
select (['othercheese', 'otherham', 'othersalad'], [3, 8, 10], [11, 22, 11])
union all
select (['othercheese', 'otherham', 'othersalad'], [3, 8, 10], [11, 22, 11])
) 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(item, unit_cost, quantity))
FROM data, UNNEST(entry.item) item WITH OFFSET
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(entry.unit_cost) unit_cost WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(entry.quantity) quantity WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "f0_": [
      {
        "item": "cheese",
        "unit_cost": "2",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "item": "ham",
        "unit_cost": "5",
        "quantity": "2"
      },
      {
        "item": "salad",
        "unit_cost": "8",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "item": "othercheese",
        "unit_cost": "3",
        "quantity": "11"
      },
      {
        "item": "otherham",
        "unit_cost": "8",
        "quantity": "22"
      },
      {
        "item": "othersalad",
        "unit_cost": "10",
        "quantity": "11"
      },
      {
        "item": "othercheese",
        "unit_cost": "3",
        "quantity": "11"
      },
      {
        "item": "otherham",
        "unit_cost": "8",
        "quantity": "22"
      },
      {
        "item": "othersalad",
        "unit_cost": "10",
        "quantity": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```